# How to retrieve the total number of items inside an observable variable in angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Observable Input variable inside a component which receives it's value from its parent component.
How can I get the number of items inside that value?

```
<tr *ngFor="let currentRow of rows | async">


</tr>
<tr>    
<td>empty message to be displayed if there are no items in the table</td>
    </tr>

Code in component
@Input() rows: Observable<IDataFlow[]>;
```

Comment: There is no number of items in an observable. That's like asking how many mousemove events are in the browser. Please add more code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: Ok. So if I want to get the underlying number of items that the observable contains so I can bind it to a view, how can I achieve it?
I tried this link but didn't get it
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/count.html

Comment: There is no underlying number of items. An observable is a subscription to events and you **can** emit a fixed number of events but in general it's not known how many items will be emitted by an observable. Why do you think you need to know?

Comment: I just want to display or hide a certain portion of a view based on whether or not there are items.

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. Usually you don't need to know the number of items in advance, therefore I have no idea what your problem is.

Comment: updated the initial post with some code. The whole idea is to show a row in a table based on the existence of data in the "rows" variable

Comment: That's what `ngFor` does. I still don't get what the problem is.

Comment: ... maybe. `ngFor` with `async` doesn't render one event below the another. Your observable would need to emit an array of items with **each** event. If you want to collect the events into an array you can use the `scan` operator.

Comment: Your code shows that the observable emits arrays of `IDataFlow` already. Therefore there shouldn't be any need for `scan`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118737/discussion-between-avi-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Ok, so here's my solution
(rows | async).length
Thanks   Günter Zöchbauer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(rows | async).length
```

to get the length of the array passed by the observable

Comment: How to do it outside the template?

Comment: `subscribe` (or perhaps `do` if you want to use it in code AND template - there are other possibilities)